# Compare participants in one column of the table and make sum from other column, js

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have a table. I'd like to compare participants. If participant have several result points in the table, the script has to return sum of all participant's results. And so on for every participant.
The table is generated from database (`".$row["pnt"]."`"`.$row["station"].`"`".$row["res"]."`):
Participant Station Points

```
aa  Some1   1
dd  Some1   2
aa  sm2 3
dd  sm2 4
bb  sm3 5
ee  sm3 6
```

> For example I've to recieve such a new table:

```
aa - 4,
dd - 6,
bb - 5,
ee - 6
```

I've tried to do so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").click(function () {

        var rows = $("tbody tr");
        var jo = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

            for (var j = 1; j <= rows.length; j++) {

                var pnt1 = $(rows[i]).find(".pnt").html();
                var stations1 = $(rows[i]).find(".station").html();
                var pntR1 = $(rows[i]).find(".res").html();
                if (pnt1 == $(rows[j]).find(".pnt").html()) {
                    pntR1 = parseInt(pntR1);
                    pntR2 = parseInt($(rows[j]).find(".res").html());
                    jo.push(pnt1, pntR1, pntR2);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        console.log(jo);

    });
});
```

But I understood that I'm on a wrong way. Please, help me. I really appreicate if some one could help me on this issue.

Updated after comments:

```
<table id="pntsRes">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Участники</th>
    <th>Баллы</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="pnt">aa</td><td class="station">AES</td><td class="res">1</td></tr><tr><td class="pnt">dd</td><td class="station">AES</td><td class="res">2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pnt">aa</td><td class="station">Science</td><td class="res">3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pnt">dd</td><td class="station">Science</td><td class="res">4</td></tr><tr><td class="pnt">bb</td><td class="station">Аэродром</td><td class="res">5</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pnt">ee</td><td class="station">aeroport</td><td class="res">6</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also give us the html. You get the `tr` elements and try to do something with them but we dont know whats inside those `tr` elements exactly.

Comment: Please provide your html too

Comment: Thank you for replies. I've updated my question with html code.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this question will be to other users of Stack Overflow. It seems very specific to your implementation. I would recommend that you attempt to use a framework such as React, Ember, or Angular. It appears that you have no separation of concerns here, and that might hurt you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would consider breaking your solution into three functions - one to extract the data from the HTML (which is a questionable practice in itself), one to transform the data, and one to output the new table. This way, your code is much more maintainable.

```
function getData() {
    var rows = $("tbody tr");
    var data = [];
    rows.each(function(idx, row){
        var pnt = row.find('.pnt').html(),
            station = row.find('.station').html()),
            res = parseInt(row.find('.res').html());
        data.push(pnt, station, res);
    });
}
```

Then I would consider something like this for the second method

```
// Pass the output from getData() into processData()
function processData(data){
    var groupedKeys = {};
    var groupedData = data.map(function(datum){
        var name = datum[0];
        var value = datum[2];
        groupedKeys[name] = (groupedKeys[name] || 0) + (value || 0);
    });
    var transformedData = [];
    Object.keys(groupedKeys).forEach(function(key){
        transformedData.push([key, groupedKeys[key]]);
        });
    return transformedData;
}
```

The last method of course would need to be implemented by yourself, there's a ton that could be improved here, but it could be a good start.

Comment: nice - much better to use functions.

Comment: @Shockwave Looks like you're a new member to SO - welcome! Don't forget to upvote good answers or comments :)

Comment: Thanks - great place to keep exercising the mind and learn new things.

Comment: Thank you very much! You code looks structured, I'll try to do my code in functions too. But your code is too hard for understanding for me as I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I used an associative array (which is just an object in JavaScript) shown below:

http://jsfiddle.net/a5k6w300/

Changes I made:

```
var jo = [];
```

changed to an object instead of an array

```
var jo = {};
```

I also added the if(isNaN(object[key]) inside the inner loop in order to make sure that these didn't show as NaN as I continued adding them together.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").click(function () {

        var rows = $("tbody tr");
        var jo = {};
  console.log(rows);
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

            for (var j = 1; j <= rows.length; j++) {

                var pnt1 = $(rows[i]).find(".pnt").html();
                var stations1 = $(rows[i]).find(".station").html();
                var pntR1 = $(rows[i]).find(".res").html();
                if (pnt1 == $(rows[j]).find(".pnt").html()) {
                    pntR1 = parseInt(pntR1);
                    pntR2 = parseInt($(rows[j]).find(".res").html());
                    if(isNaN(jo[pnt1])){
                        jo[pnt1] = 0;
                    }
                    jo[pnt1] += pntR1;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        console.log(jo);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pntsRes">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Участники</th>
            <th>Баллы</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="pnt">aa</td>
            <td class="station">AES</td>
            <td class="res">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pnt">dd</td>
            <td class="station">AES</td>
            <td class="res">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pnt">aa</td>
            <td class="station">Science</td>
            <td class="res">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pnt">dd</td>
            <td class="station">Science</td>
            <td class="res">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pnt">bb</td>
            <td class="station">Аэродром</td>
            <td class="res">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pnt">ee</td>
            <td class="station">aeroport</td>
            <td class="res">6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot.

Comment: Sure thing. Happy coding!